# What is this icon- pi symbol in circle

Tags: samsung

I have a pi symbol inside a circle on my phone's notification bar. What does this mean? [image]

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot

Comment: A quick *pi* search on Google play store showed up 3 or so apps with similar icon.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Pi music app? I get the pi symbol when Pi music is open.